# parsing a formfield value more than once using apache commons

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, apache-commons

i want to parse a multiple form field value of same input type and name along with the uploaded files,in my design iam using a java script to generate a multiple file upload field along with a text field for allowing users to  enter the file description,users can attach as many fields they want.

the java script for creating the html elements

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
var file1 = document.createElement("input");
file1.setAttribute("type", "text");
file1.setAttribute("name", "fileName"+upload_number);
d.appendChild(file1);
var file = document.createElement("input");
file.setAttribute("type", "file");
file.setAttribute("name", "attachment"+upload_number);
d.appendChild(file);
document.getElementById("moreUploads").appendChild(d);
upload_number++;
```

corresponding HTML

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';"/>
<div id="moreUploads"></div>
<div id="moreUploadsLink" style="display:none;">
  <a href="javascript:addFileInput();">Attach another File</a>
</div>
```

check,how my java script works :   http://jsfiddle.net/8k926/90/

in my file upload servlet,tried to debug and it was parsing only the first generated value,it is not parsing the next generated field occurred by javascript.

my file upload servlet

```
 if(item.isFormField())
 {  
   String name = item.getFieldName();  
   if(name != null)  
   {  
     if(name.equals("fileName"))
     {  
       fileName = item.getString();  
     }
     else if(name.equals("main"))
     {  
       main = item.getString();  
     }
     else if(name.equals("sub"))
     {
       sub=item.getString();
     }
     else if(name.equals("filetype"))
     {
       filetype=item.getString();
     }
   }  
}else{  
  String file1=item.getFieldName();
  String file2=item.getName();
  filen=file2;
  ocation = File.separator+"home"+File.separator+"adapco"+File.separator+"Desktop"+ File.separator +"output"+ File.separator +main+File.separator+sub+File.separator+filen;
  uploadFile = new File(location);    
  //code for connecting and inserting the form field values into the database. 
}
```

the debugger is exiting after uploading a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Change first Text field and File Field name to let say "fileName1" and "attachment1".

**JSP:**

```
<input type="text" name="fileName1" size="30" onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';"/>   
<input type="file" name="attachment1" id="attachment" onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';"/>
```

**Servlet:**

Iterate all fields.
Create a counter like `int cntr=1;`

```
String fileNameField="fileName";
Iterator iter = items.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
    if(item.isFormField())
     {  
       String name = item.getFieldName();  
       if(name != null)  
       {  
         if(name.equals(fileNameField+cntr))
         {  
           fileName = item.getString();  
         }
         else if(name.equals("main"))
         {  
           main = item.getString();  
         }
             else if(name.equals("sub"))
         {
        sub=item.getString();
         }
         else if(name.equals("filetype"))
         {
        filetype=item.getString();
         }
       }  
    }else{  
      String file1=item.getFieldName();
      String file2=item.getName();
      String filen=file2;
      String location = File.separator+"home"+File.separator+"adapco"+File.separator+"Desktop"+ File.separator +"output"+ File.separator +main+File.separator+sub+File.separator+filen;
      uploadFile = new File(location);    
          try {
         item.write(uploadFile);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      //code for connecting and inserting the form field values into the database. 
  }
```

Comment: thanks for ur answers @Mishra,i solved the issues by just declaring the String name = item.getFieldName();  above  if(item.isFormField())
and removed upload_number in my javascript,the upload_number will always increment whenever we attach a file,which makes the filename change from fileName(by default) to fileName2(next iteration)which will show null and parse only the previous input form field.